# Linq The specified type 'string' is not a valid provider type

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Using Linq to call a stored procedure that passes a single string,  The stored procedure returns a data set row that contains a string and an int.

Code:

```
 PESQLDataContext pe = new PESQLDataContext(strConnStr);
        pe.ObjectTrackingEnabled = false;

 gvUnitsPassed.DataSource = pe.PassedInspection(Line);
 gvUnitsPassed.DataBind();

pe.dispose();
```

When the code runs an exception gets called below:
The exception is thrown at the IExecuteResult result = statement:
Enclosed is my result class in the designer.cs file.

```
[Function(Name = "dbo.PassedInspection")]
    public ISingleResult<PassedInspectionResult> PassedInspection([Parameter(Name = "Model", DbType = "VarChar(4)")] string model)
    {
        IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())), model);
        return ((ISingleResult<PassedInspectionResult>)(result.ReturnValue));
    }

    public partial class PassedInspectionResult
    {

        private string _Date;

        private int _Passed;

        public PassedInspectionResult()
        {
        }

        [Column(Storage = "_Date", DbType = "string NULL")]
        public string Date
        {
            get
            {
                return this._Date;
            }
            set
            {
                if ((this._Date != value))
                {
                    this._Date = value;
                }
            }
        }

        [Column(Storage = "_Passed", DbType = "Int NULL")]
        public int Passed
        {
            get
            {
                return this._Passed;
            }
            set
            {
                if ((this._Passed != value))
                {
                    this._Passed = value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have other stored procedures with similar arguments that run just fine.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it's this line causing the problem:

```
[Column(Storage = "_Date", DbType = "string NULL")]
```

Specifically the "string" bit.  It should be the datatype the field is defined as in the stored proc.  eg varchar(...), ntext etc.

Comment: Yes, Thanks that was the issue.  When I first added the stored proc to the designer I had the argument as char(4).  Then I received the above error.  So I changed the argument to varchar(4).  I must have transposed the string argument.  In testing I removed the stored procedure, replaced the argument as char(4) and re added the proc.
It now maps as varchar(4) even though it is a char(4) in the stored procedure.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Thanks for saving my head from a few bonks against the wall.